# Chef handler exception handles the error, but will the chef client stop running?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

"An exception handler is used to identify situations that have caused a chef-client run to fail". But will it stop the chef-client form running? 
What should be done if I don't want the chef-client to stop running, in case an error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as I mentioned in your last question the only knob we offer is `ignore_failure`. Anything more complex than that will probably require a custom resource or some other more fancy Ruby code. Handlers (both old-school error handlers and newer event handlers) only respond to events, they cannot change Chef's overall flow control.